# What is the meaning of this name attribute and #varName in the router outlet tag?

Tags: angular

I found a code which is insrted in the app.component.html file.
In the  should be displayed the other components regarding on the routes configured in the app-routing.module.ts.

But i dont understant what is the meaning of

## o="outlet"

and
name="popup"

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular router supports having multiple outlets. this allows you to display different content based on user interaction.

I'd suggest reading the official angular documentation on [Displaying multiple routes in named outlets](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets)